# sudo npm install > Unexpected end of input for /mime/1.2.11/

Tags: npm

How do I fix this: there is something wrong with .npm/mime/1.2.11/

```
   sudo npm install express --save-dev

    npm ERR! Failed to parse json
    npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
    npm ERR! File: /home/me/.npm/mime/1.2.11/package/package.json
    npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
    npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your package.json file is not JSON format, try to paste your JSON on [http://www.jsoneditoronline.org](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) here you can see the error format; if this doesn't work try reinstall npm and nodejs.